# R: Extracting elements from data.matrix(): elements non-numeric

Tags: r

I programmed a function, which created (or at least tried to create) a data frame of numeric values. I need to retrieve these numeric values later on in the function. For that purpose, I explicitly assigned all values in the data frame a numeric class, using

```
as.numeric()
```

Later on in my function, when I extract the elements from the data frame, using

```
mydataframe[1,2]
```

I get an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator". I don't really understand what is non-numeric in my data frame.

If I ask for class and mode of the values in the data frame, they are both "numeric", storage mode is "double".  Can anyone enlighten me? Where do I go wrong?

By the way, I can extract elements without error, if I use

```
as.numeric(mydataframe[1,2])
```

But I need to extract quite a lot of elements, so I prefer all elements of my data frame being numeric.

My code:

```
mydata <- by(data, data[,index], function(data) {
*myfunction including a for-loop, creating a vector of numbers (subvar1)*}
var1 <- as.numeric(sum(subvar1) / n)
var2 <- as.numeric(mean(data[,value]))
var3 <- nrow(data)
var3 <- as.numeric(var3)
list(var1=var1, var2=var2, var3=var3)})
mydataframe <- data.matrix(do.call(rbind, mydata))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you put the outputs of `str(mydataframe)` and `dput(mydataframe)`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it by using rbind.data.frame instead of r.bind.